# term frequency calculation using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, tf-idf

Finding term frequency for documents in a list using python

`l=['cat sat besides dog']`
I have tried finding the term frequency for each word in the corpus.
term freq=(no of times word occurred in document/total number of words in a document).
I tried doing it for one document, but I'm getting an error when there's more than one document in the list.

```py
def tf(corpus):
    dic={}
    for document in corpus:
        for word in document.split():
            if word in dic:
                dic[word]+=1
            else:
                dic[word]=1
        for word,freq in dic.items():
            print(word,freq)
            dic[word]=freq/len(document.split())
    return dic
tf(d)
```

I want to pass this list and want find tf for words in each document. But I'm getting the wrong tf values.
l=['cat sat besides dog','the dog sat on bed']

Answer (score 0):

There are 3rd party packages that can do what you want. But to use your code The issue is that you are adding 1 to a frequency. So after the first attempt you update the value for `word` with its frequency in the first document. But then the next time you add 1 which is not a frequency but a count. That's why you have `sat 1.25` when you print the word and frequency.

All you need to do is move the last for loop.

`sum(map(len, (document.split() for document in corpus)))` will get the total number of words over the whole corpus.

```py
def tf(corpus):
    dic={}
    for document in corpus:
        for word in document.split():
            if word in dic:
                dic[word] = dic[word] + 1
            else:
                dic[word]=1
    for word,freq in dic.items():
        print(word,freq)
        dic[word]=freq/sum(map(len, (document.split() for document in corpus)))
    return dic
tf(d)
```

Output:

```
{'cat': 0.1111111111111111,
 'sat': 0.2222222222222222,
 'besides': 0.1111111111111111,
 'dog': 0.2222222222222222,
 'the': 0.1111111111111111,
 'on': 0.1111111111111111,
 'bed': 0.1111111111111111}
```

Frequency on each document? Just move `dic` so that is created for each document.

```py
def tf(corpus):
    tfs = []
    for document in corpus:
        dic={}
        for word in document.split():
            if word in dic:
                dic[word]+=1
            else:
                dic[word]=1
        for word,freq in dic.items():
            print(word,freq)
            dic[word]=freq/len(document.split())
        tfs.append(dic)
    return tfs
```

Output:

```
[{'cat': 0.25, 'sat': 0.25, 'besides': 0.25, 'dog': 0.25},
 {'the': 0.2, 'dog': 0.2, 'sat': 0.2, 'on': 0.2, 'bed': 0.2}]
```

Comment: firstly,Thank you for the answer,But term frequency is freq of word/total number of words in document,//'sum(map(len, (document.split() for document in corpus)))' will get the total number of words over the whole corpus.'-------here u did for whole corpus.MY requirement is freq of words/total number of words in document.

Comment: so you want the frequency for each document? Shouldn't your output then be a list instead of one dictionary? Your documents share the same word